# C# - Creating a button when another button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe I am blind, but I'v looked for an answer at this question quite a while but didn't find it. I know, probably it's pretty easy and basic, but how do you create a button once an aleardy exiting button is pressed and how do I specify what locatin and sizes to have? Thanks alot !

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about? Forms, ASP.Net, MVC, WPF, Silverlight? Could you share what you already tried?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, it is a WinForms Application. And thanks for the help !

Comment: @Alex Kayz: could you, please, add a tag `Win Forms` then?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do you create a button once an aleardy exiting button is pressed"? Why would you create a button when exiting?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: When I press button1 it creates button2. It doesn't create the same one since it aleardy exists.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is for winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(70,70);
        button.Size = new Size(100, 100);

        this.Controls.Add(button);   
}
```

Comment: you may want to give a `text` property for the button too.

Comment: You'll also need to add an event handler for this button or it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *create*, just *create* with standard `new`; `WinForms` sample:

```
// On "MyCreateButton" click
private void MyCreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button newButton = new Button() {
    Parent = this,                // place new button on the current form
    Location = new Point(10, 20), // place at x = 10, y = 20
    Text = "New button",          // Text on the button 
    //TODO: Add whatever button parameters you want 
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just create all the buttons that you need and then hide it when run ? (show only button1)
Then when button1 is clicked, show/set the button2 to visible = true.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you can do that, that's pretty cool too ! I will try it, thanks alot !